# Extend JQueryStatic with typescript

Tags: typescript

So far i have added extension methods to JQuery like this:

```
module JQueryExtensions {
    export function foo() {
        ...
    }
}
interface JQuery {
    foo(): JQuery;
}
(function ($) {
    $.fn.foo = function (): JQuery {
    ...
    return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

It was good as an extension method to a JQuery instance like $('selector').foo().
But now i need to add a static function to be able to call it like $.foo();

I Have tried replacing "JQuery" with "JQueryStatic" like this:

```
module JQueryExtensions {
    export function foo() {
        ...
    }
}
interface JQueryStatic{
    foo(): JQuery;
}
(function ($) {
    $.fn.foo = function (): JQuery {
    ...
    return this;
    };
})(JQueryStatic);
```

But it gives me the following error: "Cannot find name 'JQueryStatic'."

Comment: just pass `jQuery` instead of `JQueryStatic` and use `$.foo = ` instead of `$.fn.foo = `

Comment: Thank you @Aleksey, That Worked. Post it as an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `jQuery` (function / type definition) instead of `JQueryStatic` (interface) and use `$.foo =` (static method) instead of `$.fn.foo =` (instance method)

```
(function ($:JQueryStatic) {
    $.foo = function (): JQuery {
        ...
    };
})(jQuery);
```